# Getting regex to be more leniant

Tags: python, regex

So i saw a lot of questions yesterday asking for help about regex, i was wondering myself how to make it so that when reading from the file.

```
a0={}
# z={}
a = \
{
 }
b \
= \
{ \
 }
```

The regex should be some variation roughly of:

```
' *( *\w*) *= *{'
```

and the output should be, a0, a, b

I cant output b or a probably because its multiline and im using a for loop that reads each line.
Make sure its reading from a file not a string. Thanks

Comment: What is the ` *` inside the group for? The initial ` *` will greedily match these spaces, so the group itself will never include spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [start of string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to match any combinations of word characters which presents at the leading of the lines  :

```
>>> s="""a0={}
... # z={}
... a = \
... {
...  }
... b \
... = \
... { \
...  }"""

>>> re.findall(r'^\w+',s,re.M)
['a0', 'a', 'b']
```

> `re.M`
> (re.MULTILINE)
>
> When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character `'$'` matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, `'^'` matches only at the beginning of the string, and `'$'` only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

Comment: You should probably explain what `re.M` does.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you'll need to look at multiple lines at once, since the escaped newlines make it impossible to tell from looking at a single line whether that line is the start of an assignment statement.

You can do this either by searching within the entire string at once (as in Kasramvd's answer, which makes use of the `MULTILINE` regex flag to change the behavior of the `^` anchor) or simply concatenating lines as you see escape-characters:

```
# ... inside of some loop, with an open filehandle `f`:
line = f.readline().rstrip()
while line[-1] == '\':
    line += f.readline().rstrip()
# ... then apply your regex
```